# In iOS, how to trace the swiped distance in google maps?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've an application where I'm using Google maps SDK.
If the user is doing a wild swipe on the map view controller,(say 100miles), Then I want to take the user back to his current location.

How to implement this functionality in maps ?

How to trace the wild swipe which moved the map 100miles on the screen ?

How to know the intensity of the swipe? and how many miles that swipe take you from the current location based on the zoom level?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps iOS SDK, or Apple Maps (ie MapKit)? You've tagged your question with google-maps, mapkit and apple-maps.

Comment: Where is your problem? detecting the change in map cemter, or readimg out the current position and centerimg the map there?

Comment: @SaxonDruce: I'm using Google maps.

Comment: @AlexWien: How to trace the wild swipe which moved the map 100miles on the screen ?

Comment: is there anything like getMapCenter()?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by wild swipe? Move map 100 miles in one swipe? If so, you can add an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the map view,

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:aGMSMapView action:@selector(pan:)];
[aGMSMapView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

and implement a method to detect if the state of pan gesture is end or not. If so, check the center of the map view to determine how far you moved

```
-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //get the center of map view, and calculate distance
        CGPoint *point = aGMSMapView.center;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coor = [aGMSMapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point];
        CLLocation *mapCenter = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:coor.latitude longitude:coor.longitude];
        CLLocationDistance d = [mapCenter distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
        if (d>= 106900)
        {
            //move your map view and do whatever you want...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful adding gestures to the map: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415735/drag-pan-gestures-on-a-gmsmapview-not-getting-captured-after-update-to-sdk-1-3-1)